# SpriteKit Neighboring Hex Tiles

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, hex, tiles

I am trying to build a hex based game using Apple's SpriteKit. I'm currently stuck trying to figure out how to get the surrounding hexes of a given radius, 'N', centered around a selected tile using a SKTileMapNode. I tried using the algorithm from http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#range-coordinate, but was unsuccessfully due to the opaqueness of the SKTileMapNode coordinate system when using a Hex tiled map.

This is what I have tried so far:

`for dx -N ... N
     max = max(-N, -dx-N)
     min = min(N, -dx+N) 
     for dy max ... min 
          // place sprite at (selectedTile.col + dx, selectedTile.row + dy)`

where 'N' is the radius of the range. This is not working as intended, and I think it's cause I'm not using the *dz* coordinate that is mentioned in the site.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do using SpriteKit? I would love to stay using this engine if I can. If there are any questions, please let me know.

Comment: I believe gameplaykit supports hexagons, may want to look into it

Comment: I don't even know what the 'N' is.

Comment: Maybe I mis-worded it, but I'm trying to do something like this: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#range-coordinate

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to eventually figure it out. There was nothing wrong with the link I posted, I just didn't realize that the coordinate system that SpriteKit uses is the 'odd-r' coordinate system that is mentioned in the link, while the author uses the cubic coordinate system. What I eventually did was follow the conversion algorithms that the author supplied, and converted back and forth from cubic to 'odd-r' coordinates. Then, using the algorithm for finding the hex range supplied, I was able to implement the correct functionality.

To sum things up...always read the whole article and not just what you're interested in!

Sources:

http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#conversions-offset